# How to convert binary sum to binary in O(n)

Tags: c++, binary

I am trying to find an optimal solution for convertimg binaries to binaries. I am keeping large numbers in an array using powers of 2 and keeping a sum.For example I am keeping the number $2^{3} + 4x2^{2} + 5x2^{1}$ = 29 in an array of 4 as this {0,5,4,1} where each place of the array has the times that each power of two appears.  After my program finishes I want to convert this array in an array that produces the same sum but has only one or zero in the array. In ither words I want to convert this sum to binary. So my example would give the array {1,0,1,1,1} = 29

How could I do this conversion in c ++ in O(n)

My current solution is O($n^{2}$) and is the following:

```
bool bl = true;
    while (bl) {
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            if (num[i] != 0 && num[i] != 1) {
                vector<long int> p = block(num[i]);
                num[i] = 0;

                for (auto j = 0; j < p.size(); ++j) {
                    if (p[j]!=0)
                        num[j + i] += 1;
                }
            }
        }


        bl = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            if (num[i] == 0 || num[i] == 1) {
                bl = false;
                continue;
            }
            else {

                bl = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= M; i++)
    {
        cout << i << ':' << num[i] << '\n';
    }
```

Comment: where do you get this from `2^{3} + 4x2^{2} + 5x2^{1}` ? This is not binary representation, it is also not a prime factorization, what is it?

Comment: this is a subproblem, I have a tree with edges that have weight equal to some power of two and I am supposed to calculate the sum of all the minimum paths.

Comment: How do you get `{1,01,1,1} = 29` ?

Comment: @Damien I edited it was a typo

Comment: `16+4+2+1=23`. I guess I miss something.

Comment: @Damien I wrote it in reverse order so it is just 1+0+4+8+16=29

Answer (score 0):

You know that `(2k+j)*2^N === j*2^N + k*2^(N+1)`, so you can just "roll" values >= 2 forward:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
    if (num[i] < 2)
        continue;

    if (i+1 == num.size()) {
        if (num.size() == num.capacity())
            num.reserve(num.size() + 5);
        num.push_back(0);
    }

    num[i+1] += num[i] / 2;
    num[i] %= 2;
}
```

Note that this grows the storage by 5 elements per turn on overflow. If you expect gigantic numbers you may want to tweak this value to reduce the amount of vector copying.